# GeoSPARQL functions and spatial reference systems (SRS)

Tags: spatial, graphdb, geosparql

I am trying to represent in an ontology a few geometric objects (*polygon*, *lines*, *points*, etc.) and calculate their spatial/topological relations, through the adoption of **GeoSPARQL** relevant functions (*sfTouches*, *sfEquals*, *sfContains*, etc.). I am using GraphDB, with the GeoSPARQL plugin enabled.

I have seen that in the [WKT representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) of the geometric object, GeoSPARQL uses the concept of a default spatial reference system (i.e. the <http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84> URI which corresponds to the [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) coordinate reference system (*CRS*)). However, in my use case, the coordinates of the geometrical objects actually correspond to values in **a 2D Cartesian coordinate system**.

I found in the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org/) the proper CRS for representing Cartesian coordinates and I attached the proper URI in the WKT representation, but the GeoSPARQL functions do not return any result or error.

My question is the following: "*Do the GeoSPARQL functions operate properly when representing spatial objects in any other type of CRS, apart from the default one?*".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently GDB does not support alternative CRS in WKT literals but supports them in GML literals (issue GDB-3142). GML literals are slightly more complex but still easy enough to generate, let us know if you need help with that.

However, I question your assertion that you have Cartesian coordinates. On one hand,  any pair (lat,long) or (nothing,easting) is a Cartesian coordinate. On the other hand,  since the Earth is not flat, any CRS or projection method is only an approximation,  and many of them are tuned for specific localities.

So please tell us which EPSG CRS you picked,  and a bit about the locality of your data.

Comment: Thank you @VladimirAlexiev for your reply! My aim is to infer spatial relations between objects detected by an _object detection system_. Objects are populated in an ontology, in a form of polygons, each point of which is projected in a X,Y Cartesian system. Axis have limits; `x_min=0, x_max=1280, y_min=0, y_max=960`. I've experimented with different CRSs: e.g. 4499 (http://www.opengis.net/def/cs/EPSG/0/4499), 4530, etc. However, none of the GeoSPARQL function (e.g. `geof:sfTouches, geof:sfContains`, etc.) return any result. So, is it really a GraphDB-CRS or a GeoSPARQL-CRS issue?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your geometries are not fixed to a particular location on Earth. I checked CRS 4499, and if your coordinates are in meters, it should fill the bill.

Given the previous answer: do you use GML literals to load your geometries in GDB? Can you share a turtle file with a couple of features, so we can test?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, you understand right. My geometries have nothing to do with geo references. Imagine them as polygons or points in a XY coordinate system (see my previous answer). Unfortunately, I only tried the _WKT literal_ representations since I am not aware of how to initialise my data with _GML literals_. I  will now include an example instantiation in a following comment. Thank you @Vladimir for your help and time.

Comment: In the following triples I represent a polygon and a point within it. When running GeoSPARQL (e.g. function geof:sfContains, or geof:sfWithin) through GraphDB, it returns no results.

Comment: ex:polygon_ABCD
  rdf:type ex:ExampleEntity ;
  geo:hasGeometry ex:geometry_polygon_ABCD ;
.

ex:geometry_polygon_ABCD
  rdf:type geo:Geometry ;
  rdf:type sf:Polygon ;
  geo:asWKT "<http://www.opengis.net/def/cs/EPSG/0/4499> Polygon((389.0 1052.0, 563.0 1052.0, 563.0 1280.0, 389.0 1280.0, 389.0 1052.0))"^^geo:wktLiteral ;
.

ex:point_E
  rdf:type ex:ExampleEntity ;
  geo:hasGeometry ex:geometry_point_E ;
.

ex:geometry_point_E
  rdf:type geo:Geometry ;
  rdf:type sf:Point ;
  geo:asWKT "<http://www.opengis.net/def/cs/EPSG/0/4499> Point(400.0 1100.0)"^^geo:wktLiteral ;
.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to format the aforementioned triples in a comment here.. so, please copy-paste them in a notepad to see more clear the given instantiations. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 0):

Your example, slightly reformatted, and using normal turtle shortenings:

```
ex:polygon_ABCD rdf:type ex:ExampleEntity ;
  geo:hasGeometry ex:geometry_polygon_ABCD .

ex:geometry_polygon_ABCD a geo:Geometry, sf:Polygon ;
  geo:asWKT "<opengis.net/def/cs/EPSG/0/4499> Polygon((389.0 1052.0, 563.0 1052.0, 563.0 1280.0, 389.0 1280.0, 389.0 1052.0))"^^geo:wktLiteral .

ex:point_E rdf:type ex:ExampleEntity ; 
  geo:hasGeometry ex:geometry_point_E . 

ex:geometry_point_E a geo:Geometry, sf:Point ;
  geo:asWKT "<opengis.net/def/cs/EPSG/0/4499> Point(400.0 1100.0)"^^geo:wktLiteral ; .
```

You must use a specific URL for the CRS and cannot omit `http:`, so the correct URL is http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4499.

But you can see from the returned description that this CRS is applocable to "China - onshore and offshore between 120°E and 126°E". I'm not an expert in geo projections so I can't guarantee whether this CRS will satisfy your need "leave my coordinates alone, they are just meters". I'd look for a UK (OrdnanceSurvey) CRS with easting and northing coordinates.

To learn how to format GML:

- see the GeoSPARQL spec (OGC 11-052r4) p18, whchc gives an example about `gml:Point`.
- then google for `gml:Polygon`. There are many links but one that gives examples is http://www.georss.org/gml.html

Armed with this knowledge, we can reformat your example to GML:

```xml
ex:polygon_ABCD rdf:type ex:ExampleEntity ;
  geo:hasGeometry ex:geometry_polygon_ABCD .

ex:geometry_polygon_ABCD a geo:Geometry, sf:Polygon ;
  geo:asGML """
      <gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/TODO">
         <gml:exterior>
            <gml:LinearRing>
               <gml:posList>
389.0 1052.0, 563.0 1052.0, 563.0 1280.0, 389.0 1280.0, 389.0 1052.0
               </gml:posList>
            </gml:LinearRing>
         </gml:exterior>
      </gml:Polygon>
"""^^geo:gmlLiteral.

ex:point_E rdf:type ex:ExampleEntity ; 
  geo:hasGeometry ex:geometry_point_E . 

ex:geometry_point_E a geo:Geometry, sf:Point ;
  geo:asGML """
      <gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/TODO">
        <gml:pos>
      400.0 1100.0
        </gml:pos>  
      </gml:Point>
"""^^geo:gmlLiteral.
```

- The `"""` (long quote) allows us to use `"` inside the literal without quoting
- replace `TODO` with the better CRS you picked
- the documentation http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/master/enterprise/geosparql-support.html#geosparql-examples gives an example similar to yours but it cheats a bit because all coordinates are in the range (-90,+90) so it can just use WGS.
- after you debug using `geof:` topology functions, turn on indexing and switch to `geo:` predicates, because the functions are slow (they check every geometry against every other) while the predicates use the special geo index

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: In the current release of GDB, non- default CRS are supported in both WKT and GML literals

Comment: Thank you for the great instructions Vladimir. I was able to reproduce the example with the GML literals however this representation couldn't solve my problem. 

In your latest comment, do you declare that there is an update in the GraphDB that now supports non-default CRS? Is there a list of URIs that point to the supported CRS? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, GraphDB now supports any CRS in both WKT and GML. The list of CRS URIs is available starting at http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/ and there are several hundred to choose from